How to compile and run a single verilog file with Questa?
How to compile and run a single verilog/systemverilog file with Questa simulator?
Edit (some background and initial attempts):
During hardware development, the verilog source code can be compiled and run as any other software code. In this case using the Questa suite (see https://eda.sw.siemens.com/en-US/ic/questa/simulation/advanced-simulator/)
What is the command sequence to compile and run a .v or .sv file with Questa suite? I tried just running vsim my_module.v but that was not enough.

I tried to add some background and details to make it clearer, are there other details or clarification that people want?

To compile your Verilog file, use:
vlog file.v

Then, run the simulation with Questa using:
vsim your_module


Thanks, I used `vsim my_module -c -do 'run; quit;'
